# Retrieval of hierarchial data

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a region code to select area based on type in one query.

**Table `place`:**

```
regionname regiontype placeid parentplaceid
-------------------------------------------
Chennai    city        4        2
Bangalore  city        3        1
TamilNadu  state       2        2
Karnataka  state       1        1
```

**Table `Country`:**

```
countryname State

India       TamilNadu
India       Karnataka
```

```
select  c.countryname, p.regionname, c.State
from place p,
     country c
where p.regionname = c.State
```

**Expected:**

```
India       TamilNadu   TamilNadu
India       Karnataka   Karnataka
India       Chennai     TamilNadu
India       Bangalore   Karnataka
```

**Actual**

```
India       TamilNadu   TamilNadu
India       Karnataka   Karnataka
```

Comment: do you have any key or id in your tables?

Comment: no keys in the table

Comment: Why do you expect a result with the values "Bangalore" and "Karnataka" on a row, when in your condition you filter out rows where those are not equal?

Comment: banglore is a city in karnataka, it uses parentplace as id regardless where there it is a city, town or state.Every city and town has parentplace pointing to the the state it belong and state has its own id.

Comment: What is the column p.placename? It's not on your table definition.

Comment: You should probably split your place table into state and city tables, as that would form a more natural hierarchy of country > state > city.

Comment: i have corrected it now.thanks, purpose is to use placeid and parentplaceid in a single select to retrive

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i am using postgres

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+hierarchical-data+recursive-query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701519/5962802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems rather complicated.  You can do what you want using `union all` -- one part for the states and one for the cities.

```
select c.countryname, p.regionname, p.state
from place p join
     country c
     on p.regiontype = 'state' and
        p.regionname = c.state
union all
select c.countryname, p.regionname, ps.state
from place p join
     place ps
     on p.parentplaceid = ps.placeid and
        p.regiontype = 'city' and
        ps.regiontype = 'state' join
     country c
     on ps.regionname = c.state;
```